# how to edit only one post instead of iterative loop all posts?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using `foreach($user->posts as $post)` on my input field so that i am able to use this `value="{{ old('about') ?? $post->about }}"` because without the iteration i get an error (trying to get property of an object) when using the value. However, I do not what my edit.blade to look like this when  trying to edit
I only need one single input field for only one particular post which I'm trying to edit

[image]

### edit.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<form action="/p/update/{{ $user->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

@csrf
@method ('PATCH')

<div class="col-8 offset-2">
<div class="form-group row">

@foreach($user->posts as $post)
    <label for="about" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __(' post about') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="about" type="text" class="form-control @error('about') is-invalid @enderror" name="about"  value="{{ old('about') ?? $post->about }}" required autocomplete="about" autofocus>

    @error('about')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
    </div>
@endforeach

    <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __(' post image') }}</label>
    <input type="file", class="form-control-file" id ="image" name="image"  >
    @error('image')
            <div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong> </div>
    @enderror
      <div class="btn btn-primary">
      <button> save </button>
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
</form>
</div>
@endsection
```

### route

```
Route::get('/post/edit/{user}', 'PostController@edit')->name('post.edit');


Route::patch('/p/update/{user}', 'PostController@update')->name('post.update');
```

### PostController

```
 public function edit(User $user)
{
   

  return view('posts.edit', compact('user'));
}

 public function update(User $user)
{
$data = request()->validate([
    'about' => 'required',
    'image' => '',

  ]);

  if(request('image')){
    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads','public');
    $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(500,500);
  
    $image->save();

    $imageArray = ['image' => $imagePath];

  }
  auth()->user()->posts()->update(array_merge( $data, $imageArray ?? [] ) );
  
  return redirect("/user/{$user->id} ");
}
```

Comment: what you trying to achieve exactly ? it'n not clear in your question

Comment: i only what to show  a  single input field for a particular post that i choose to edit.  i believe the iteration is grabbing all the input fields for the post but am using it to prevent an error in order to use the post->about

Comment: add your controller and route code to your question in order to help you

Comment: why you pass user not post in your route and controller ?

Comment: @IBRAHIMEZZAT  thinking i will need the user somehow.... let me make that change and see how it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to pass one post to edit you have to pass this post like:

**Route**

```
Route::get('/post/edit/{post}', 'PostController@edit')->name('post.edit');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function edit(Post $post)
{
   
  return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
}
```

**Blade file**

```
<label for="about" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __(' post about') }}</label>

<div class="col-md-6">
<input id="about" type="text" class="form-control @error('about') is-invalid @enderror" name="about"  value="{{ old('about') ?? $post->about }}" required autocomplete="about" autofocus>

    @error('about')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: this is taking me way back the link in my home.blade to the edit.blade is passing the user object                      <div> <a href="/post/edit/{{$user->id}}"> edit post </a> </div> It is the one that is  giving the variable to the route get('/post/edit/{post}......... which is ending up telling me route not found